# Add missing driver to legacy project in production

Tags: java, deployment, runtime

I am migrating a legacy project to a new server. Previously the project used a Oracle DB but now i want it to use Postgress. The queries are simple enough and work the same in Postgres.

However the project is missing a Postgres jdbc-driver. Can i somehow add this dependency sideways to the jar without recompiling?

Comment: No. if you use `java -jar` to run your app then you have to change manifest file inside jar.

Answer (score 1):

> Can i somehow add this dependency to the jar without recompiling?

It depends.

- If you are running the server as `java -jar myserver.jar ...`, then you will *at least* need to modify the manifest in the JAR file.  Strictly speaking this doesn't entail *recompiling*, but you do need to explode, modify and repack the JAR file.
- If the server uses `Class.forName` to explicitly load an Oracle `Driver` class, then you will need to change that code to load the Postgres `Driver` class instead.  (There are other ways to use JDBC that avoid this, but this depends on how your legacy server is implemented.)
- If your server uses Oracle specific database classes, or Oracle specific SQL features (or it needs to do the same in the Postgres world) then more extensive changes will be required.

But without actually examining your codebase in detail, we can't predict what is required.

My advice is to replace the Oracle driver JAR with a Postgres driver JAR, and see what happens when you run your server against a Postgres database with the appropriate schemas and data.

But I wouldn't do this "in production".  Do it in a test environment.  If you can't set up a suitable test environment ... forget it.

And if you don't have the source code for your server, I would forget it too.  If anything goes wrong you will most likely need source code to figure out the problem and fix it.